# Find all values of parameters to make a certain function continuous.

Tags: calculus

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\sin(x^2 - 4)}{x-2} & \text{if $x \in (-\infty, 2)$} \\
ax+b & \text{if $x \in [2,5]$} \\
{\sqrt{4(\ln(x-5))^2 + 1} \over \ln(x-5)} & \text{if $x \in (5, \infty)$}
\end{cases}$$

My process is equating the limit as $x$ approaches $2$ from the left and from the right:

\begin{gather*}
\lim_{x\to 2^-} \frac{\sin(x^2 - 4)}{x-2} = L = 4\\
\lim_{x\to 2^+} ax+b = L = 2a+b
\end{gather*}

Then $2a+b = 4 \implies b = 4 - 2a$.

---

\begin{gather*}
\lim_{x\to 5^-} ax+b = -5a+b \\
\lim_{x\to 5^+} {\sqrt{4(\ln(x-5))^2 + 1} \over \ln(x-5)}  = -2
\end{gather*}

Then $-5a+b = -2$

---

$\therefore -5a+4-2a = -2 $

$\therefore -7a = -6$

$\therefore a = 6/7$

Is this right for getting the $a$ part?

Comment: I started formatting this, but then I got to "My process", and I couldn't make head or tail of what you were trying to express. What expression are you taking a limit of as $x$ approaches what?

Comment: @dfeuer My process is equating the limit as x approaches 2^- and 2^+. So equating the limit for the top function in the peicewise and the middle one. Then the middle one and the bottom one

Comment: Please check to make sure I did not change your meaning. Also, please try to read the help/FAQ on using MathJax correctly.

Comment: sorry for the terrible formatting :(

Comment: @Audr:  Are u interested in a machinery approach doing the problem by Maple?

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty good! You just made a small sign mistake. You should have:
$$
\lim_{x\to 5^-} ax+b = \color{red}{+5}a+b
$$

Hence, by equating the left hand side and right hand side limits and substituting, we obtain:
$$
-2 = 5a + b = 5a + (4-2a) = 3a + 4 \iff -6 = 3a \iff \boxed{a = -2}
$$

Comment: ? But it is approaching from the negative side. Shouldn't it be $-5a + b$ ?

Comment: No. Note that since $ax+b$ is continuous, we are allowed to "plug in" the value of $5$ for $x$, and the way we approach it (from the left or from the right) is irrelevant. More generally, for any function $g(x)$ that is continuous at $x=k$, we have:
$$
\lim_{x\to k^-} g(x) = \lim_{x\to k^+} g(x) = \lim_{x\to k} g(x)
 = g(k)$$

Comment: Mmm.. why is this rule true though?

Comment: It follows from the fact that *the limit of $g(x)$ as $x$ approaches $k$ exists if and only if its left hand limit and right hand limit also exist and are equal to each other* together with the definition of continuity. See Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions